# How to troubleshoot WD My Cloud Home connection

Tags: macos, network, nas

I've got a WD My Cloud Home that I use as my personal NAS. I installed the software WD Discovery (in a Mac Mini with OS version 10.11.6) so it could detect such device. Until now, it has been working fine, but recently the WD drive isn't shown in Finder, so I cannot access its contents. WD Discovery still detects it, but when clicking on the device, the folder isn't shown either.

Nonetheless, I can access its contents via web and through another Mac Mini with the latest OS, so the NAS is working fine. Therefore, I was wondering what steps should I take in order to troubleshoot the connection of a Mac with a NAS.

Thank you.